# returning values in a bash function

Tags: linux, bash

I'm working with a growing bash script and within this script I have a number of functions. One of these functions is supposed to return a variables value, but I am running into some issues with the syntax. Below is an example of the code.

```
ShowTags() {
    local tag=0
    read tag
    echo "$tag"
}

selected_tag=$(ShowTags)
echo "$selected_tag"
```

pulled this code from a Linux Journal article, but the problem is it doesn't seem to work, or perhaps it does and im missing something. Essentially whenever the function is called the script hangs up and does not output anything, I need to CTRL+C to drop back to CLI.

The article in question is below.

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions

So my question is this the proper way to return a value? Is there a better or more dependable way of doing this? And if there is please give me an example so I can figure this out without using global variables.

EDIT:

The behavior of this is really getting to me now. I am using the following script.

```
ShowTags() {  

     echo "hi"
     local tag=0
     read tag
     echo "$tag"
}            

selected_tag=$(ShowTags)
echo "$selected_tag
```

Basically what happens is bash will act as if the read command is taking place before the echo tag at the top of the function. As soon as I pass something to read though it will run the top echo, and complete the rest of the script. I am not sure why this is happening. This is exactly what is happening in my main script.

Comment: Why did you edit the code in the question? Now it's exactly the same as in the answer, so the answer makes no sense. Was that a copying error when you wrote the question?

Comment: I edited the code to reflect it as it appears in my script. The issue isn't syntax. The script simply hangs up when I attempt to call the function via command substitution.

Comment: The `read tag` command is waiting for you to type something.

Comment: I tried it, it works fine for me. After typing `selected_tag=$(ShowTags)` I typed something. Then `echo "$selected_tag"` showed what I typed.

Comment: I updated my top post with a quick script I put together, and a better explanation of what bash is doing.

Comment: Everything that the function echoes will be stored into `selected_tag`, it won't be displayed immediately.

Comment: Well that makes more sense now. Bash is basically waiting to return all stdout at the end of the function, including a printf in my function (main script), is there a way around this or do I just need to put any stdout outside the function to compensate for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `echo "hi"` to `echo "hi" >/dev/tty`.

The reason you're not seeing it immediately is that `$(ShowTags)` captures all the standard output of the function, and that gets assigned to `selected_tag`. So you don't see any of it until you echo that variable.

By redirecting the prompt to `/dev/tty`, it's always displayed immediately on the terminal, not sent to the function's `stdout`, so it doesn't get captured by the command substitution.

Comment: Thank You! I'm so glad I finally figured out the issue at hand. Your a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to define a function with `Name { ... ]`. You have to use `name() { ... }`:

```
ShowTags() {    # add ()
local tag=0
read tag
echo "$tag"
}               # End with }

selected_tag=$(ShowTags)
echo "$selected_tag"
```

It now lets the user type in a string and have it written back:

```
$ bash myscript 
hello world     # <- my input
hello world     # script's output
```

You can add a prompt with `read -p "Enter tag: " tag` to make it more obvious when to write your input.

Comment: I just threw this into a new script and ran it, the script just hangs up without asking for user input. I threw in an echo at the beginning of the function to see if it is even getting through and it doesn't appear so because it doesn't get displayed. Could it be something to do with the way my bash is setup?

Comment: @barefly Anything the function echoes will be put into `$selected_tag`, you won't see it on the screen.

Comment: @barefly the `echo` output will have been captured by `$(ShowTags)` along with the other output. You can use stderr (`echo "starting function" >&2`) to bypass this (it's pretty much what stderr is for).

Answer (score 0):

As @thatotherguy pointed out, your function declaration syntax is off; but I suspect that's a transcription error, as if it was wrong in the script you'd get different problems. I think what's going on is that the `read tag` command in the function is trying to read a value from standard input (by default that's the terminal), and pausing until you type something in. I'm not sure what it's intended to do, but as written I'd expect it to pause indefinitely until something's typed in.

Solution: either type something in, or use something other than `read`. You could also add a prompt (`read -p "Enter a tag: " tag`) to make it more clear what's going on.

BTW, I have a couple of objections to the [linux journal article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions) you linked. These aren't relevant to your script, but things you should be aware of.

First, the `function` keyword is a nonstandard bashism, and I recommend against using it. `myfunc() ...` is sufficient to introduce a function definition.

Second, and more serious, the article recommends using `eval` in an unsafe way. Actually, it's really hard to use `eval` safely (see [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)). You can improve it a great deal just by changing the quoting, and even more by not using `eval` at all:

```
eval $__resultvar="'$myresult'"    # BAD, can evaluate parts of $myresult as executable code
eval $__resultvar='"$myresult"'    # better, is only vulnerable to executing $__resultvar
declare $__resultvar="$myresult"   # better still
```

See [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) for more options  and discussion.